# How to create Kaplan Meier plot for grouped data?

Tags: r, demographics

do you know a way how to make Kaplan Meier plot for grouped data in R? I do not have invidual data, justa number of newborns, number of people that riched 1,2...12 year.
Thanks.

The data are:

```
data <- tibble::tribble(
      ~age,  ~male, ~female,
        0L, 48415L,  46450L,
        1L, 41292L,  40316L,
        2L, 38717L,  37735L,
        3L, 37310L,  36314L,
        4L, 36318L,  35338L,
        5L, 34996L,  34044L,
        6L, 34022L,  33124L,
        7L, 33378L,  32507L,
        8L, 32807L,  31957L,
        9L, 32341L,  31560L,
       10L, 32054L,  31247L,
       11L, 31847L,  31070L,
       12L, 31633L,  30815L
      )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081097/kaplan-meier-iteratively, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+Kaplan+Meier+plot

Comment: A Kaplan Meier estimator works with the time to a certain event, so you may have to make assumptions with these particular data (e.g. 48,415 male newborns, 41,292 one-year-olds: did 7,123 of them die before reaching the first year, or are these not the same individuals?). Furthermore, the goal of such estimators is mainly to handle *censoring*, which doesn't really seem to be collected or at least indicated here. The crude solution may be to just divide all numbers by the value at start & plot those fractions?

Comment: 48415 were male newborns of them  7 123 die befte the reaching first year.  Those are data from the 19th century. Therefore infant mortality was hight. In my case almost 15%.

Comment: That is data in life table format. You should be looking at demography oriented packages. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D++plot+life+table